# I need fake country names for my story

Tags: world-building, writers-block

I have a bad case of writer's block, and I need some realistic-sounding country names for my story. Nothing too "exotic" or hard to pronounce, please. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Writers! In its current state, your question will likely be closed due to a lack of details. If you can edit your question to better explain what kind of names you are looking for and in what specific area you are having trouble (coming up with bad names, or coming up with no names at all, etc.) we might be able to help you.

Comment: I would refer you to this question: https://writers.stackexchange.com/q/23957/10394 It also has helpful links to other similar questions which should prove helpful.

Comment: Hi Wurrie and welcome to Writers.  Asking us to generate names for you isn't a good fit for this site.  Asking *how* to generate good names is on-topic if you describe what makes a name "good" -- are you looking for certain linguistic properties, something that takes your world's mythology into account (you'd have to explain that), something with particular imagery, etc?  See the question that Thomas linked for an example.  If by "good" you meant realistic then that question should help; if you meant something else, please [edit] to explain and we can look at taking this off hold.  Thanks.

Comment: I second @ThomasMyron's suggestion. Short of actually providing a list (which is obviously "what to write", and off topic), the answers to that question seem to cover everything the poster could need for coming up with realistic-sounding names.

Comment: You mentioned writer's block. You might want to see the other questions under the [tag:writers-block] tag, especially https://writers.stackexchange.com/q/20087/10027 and https://writers.stackexchange.com/q/2100/10027

Comment: I'd use "crosses" of real country names: "Fritain," "Permany," "Bolland,: etc.

Answer (score 1):

Nations of the East, 
United South, 
Gorox of the Abyss, 
United will of the Leaders, 
Nation of peril, 
Nation of Peace, 
United Peace, 
The Cross Foundation, 
The Foundations of the North, 
The South Nations, 
The Bright Nations.